# Access of R.drawable in Android Studio throws a KotlinFrontEndException

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

For Android development I use Kotlin with the Kotlin plugin 0.10.206. When I try to access a resource via R.drawable. Android Studio (1.0.2) shows in the Event log that a KotlinFrontEndException occoured every time I do something in that file (add code/delete code/scroll). Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in the plugin? Does anybody know a solution?

Here is one of the code parts that causes the Exception:

```
val notification = notificationBuilder
                .extend(NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addPage(secondPageNotification)
                        .setBackground(loadBitmapFromAsset(R.drawable.clock_background))
                )
                .build()
```

Here is the Exception description:

```
Exception in processing references for copy paste in file MainActivity.kt}: Exception while analyzing expression at (218,60) in /Users/jp/AndroidStudioProjects/.../MainActivity.kt:
         R.drawable.clock_background

at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingServices.java:173)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.ArgumentTypeResolver.getArgumentTypeInfo(ArgumentTypeResolver.java:187)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.ArgumentTypeResolver.analyzeArgumentsAndRecordTypes(ArgumentTypeResolver.java:254)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallResolver.doResolveCall(CallResolver.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallResolver.doResolveCallOrGetCachedResults(CallResolver.java:359)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallResolver.resolveFunctionCall(CallResolver.java:312)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getResolvedCallForFunction(CallExpressionResolver.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getCallExpressionTypeInfoWithoutFinalTypeCheck(CallExpressionResolver.java:184)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getCallExpressionTypeInfo(CallExpressionResolver.java:167)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.visitCallExpression(BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.java:689)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.visitCallExpression(BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.java:88)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetCallExpression.accept(JetCallExpression.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.visitJetElement(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.visitJetElement(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:36)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitExpression(JetVisitor.java:162)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitReferenceExpression(JetVisitor.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitCallExpression(JetVisitor.java:254)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetCallExpression.accept(JetCallExpression.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:136)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingServices.java:173)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.ArgumentTypeResolver.getArgumentTypeInfo(ArgumentTypeResolver.java:187)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.ArgumentTypeResolver.analyzeArgumentsAndRecordTypes(ArgumentTypeResolver.java:254)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallResolver.doResolveCall(CallResolver.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallResolver.doResolveCallOrGetCachedResults(CallResolver.java:359)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallResolver.resolveFunctionCall(CallResolver.java:312)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getResolvedCallForFunction(CallExpressionResolver.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getCallExpressionTypeInfoWithoutFinalTypeCheck(CallExpressionResolver.java:184)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getSelectorReturnTypeInfo(CallExpressionResolver.java:267)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getQualifiedExpressionTypeInfo(CallExpressionResolver.java:296)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.visitQualifiedExpression(BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.java:683)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.visitQualifiedExpression(BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.java:88)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitDotQualifiedExpression(JetVisitor.java:270)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetDotQualifiedExpression.accept(JetDotQualifiedExpression.java:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.visitJetElement(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.visitJetElement(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:36)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitExpression(JetVisitor.java:162)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitQualifiedExpression(JetVisitor.java:262)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitDotQualifiedExpression(JetVisitor.java:270)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetDotQualifiedExpression.accept(JetDotQualifiedExpression.java:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:136)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingServices.java:173)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.ArgumentTypeResolver.getArgumentTypeInfo(ArgumentTypeResolver.java:187)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.ArgumentTypeResolver.analyzeArgumentsAndRecordTypes(ArgumentTypeResolver.java:254)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallResolver.doResolveCall(CallResolver.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallResolver.doResolveCallOrGetCachedResults(CallResolver.java:359)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallResolver.resolveFunctionCall(CallResolver.java:312)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getResolvedCallForFunction(CallExpressionResolver.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getCallExpressionTypeInfoWithoutFinalTypeCheck(CallExpressionResolver.java:184)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getSelectorReturnTypeInfo(CallExpressionResolver.java:267)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getQualifiedExpressionTypeInfo(CallExpressionResolver.java:296)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.visitQualifiedExpression(BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.java:683)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.visitQualifiedExpression(BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.java:88)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitDotQualifiedExpression(JetVisitor.java:270)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetDotQualifiedExpression.accept(JetDotQualifiedExpression.java:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.visitJetElement(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.visitJetElement(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:36)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitExpression(JetVisitor.java:162)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitQualifiedExpression(JetVisitor.java:262)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitDotQualifiedExpression(JetVisitor.java:270)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetDotQualifiedExpression.accept(JetDotQualifiedExpression.java:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:136)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingServices.java:173)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getQualifiedExpressionTypeInfo(CallExpressionResolver.java:287)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.visitQualifiedExpression(BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.java:683)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.visitQualifiedExpression(BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.java:88)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitDotQualifiedExpression(JetVisitor.java:270)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetDotQualifiedExpression.accept(JetDotQualifiedExpression.java:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.visitJetElement(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.visitJetElement(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:36)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitExpression(JetVisitor.java:162)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitQualifiedExpression(JetVisitor.java:262)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitDotQualifiedExpression(JetVisitor.java:270)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetDotQualifiedExpression.accept(JetDotQualifiedExpression.java:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:136)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingServices.java:168)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getType(ExpressionTypingServices.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.safeGetType(ExpressionTypingServices.java:161)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.DescriptorResolver.resolveInitializerType(DescriptorResolver.java:1168)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.DescriptorResolver.getVariableType(DescriptorResolver.java:1066)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.DescriptorResolver.resolveLocalVariableDescriptor(DescriptorResolver.java:884)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorForStatements.visitProperty(ExpressionTypingVisitorForStatements.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorForStatements.visitProperty(ExpressionTypingVisitorForStatements.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetProperty.accept(JetProperty.java:57)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:136)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getBlockReturnedTypeWithWritableScope(ExpressionTypingServices.java:308)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getBlockReturnedType(ExpressionTypingServices.java:244)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getBlockReturnedType(ExpressionTypingServices.java:210)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorForStatements.visitBlockExpression(ExpressionTypingVisitorForStatements.java:385)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorForStatements.visitBlockExpression(ExpressionTypingVisitorForStatements.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetBlockExpression.accept(JetBlockExpression.java:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:136)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.checkFunctionReturnType(ExpressionTypingServices.java:205)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.checkFunctionReturnType(ExpressionTypingServices.java:190)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.BodyResolver.resolveFunctionBody(BodyResolver.java:618)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.BodyResolver.resolveFunctionBodies(BodyResolver.java:592)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.BodyResolver.resolveBehaviorDeclarationBodies(BodyResolver.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.BodyResolver.resolveBodies(BodyResolver.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.java:330)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.plugin.caches.resolve.KotlinResolveDataProvider.analyze(KotlinResolveCache.kt:258)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.plugin.caches.resolve.PerFileAnalysisCache.analyze(KotlinResolveCache.kt:179)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.plugin.caches.resolve.PerFileAnalysisCache.analyze$b$2(KotlinResolveCache.kt:126)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.plugin.caches.resolve.PerFileAnalysisCache.getAnalysisResults(KotlinResolveCache.kt:164)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.plugin.caches.resolve.KotlinResolveCache.getAnalysisResultsForElements(KotlinResolveCache.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.plugin.caches.resolve.KotlinCacheService$getResolutionFacade$1.analyzeFullyAndGetResult(KotlinCacheService.kt:66)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.plugin.caches.resolve.ResolvePackage$resolutionApi$859eb6cc.analyzeFullyAndGetResult(resolutionApi.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.plugin.highlighter.JetPsiChecker.annotate(JetPsiChecker.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.plugin.highlighter.JetPsiCheckerAndHighlightingUpdater.annotate(JetPsiCheckerAndHighlightingUpdater.java:29)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.runAnnotators(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:160)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.visit(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:103)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$5.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:312)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:397)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.access$300(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:64)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$6.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:403)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.analyze(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:87)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:400)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.access$300(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:64)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$6.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:403)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.RefCountHolder.analyze(RefCountHolder.java:318)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.HighlightVisitorImpl.analyze(HighlightVisitorImpl.java:173)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:400)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.collectHighlights(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:388)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.collectInformationWithProgress(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:230)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.doCollectInformation(ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.java:86)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:62)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass$1$1.run(PassExecutorService.java:380)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1154)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass$1.run(PassExecutorService.java:371)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:368)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:344)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:193)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:858)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1687)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1642)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid identifier: 
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.name.Name.identifier(Name.java:56)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.java.structure.impl.JavaMemberImpl.getName(JavaMemberImpl.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.java.lazy.descriptors.ClassMemberIndex$fields$1.invoke(MemberIndex.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.java.lazy.descriptors.ClassMemberIndex$fields$1.invoke(MemberIndex.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.utils.UtilsPackage$collections$8c8c85b0.valuesToMap(collections.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.utils.UtilsPackage.valuesToMap(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.java.lazy.descriptors.ClassMemberIndex.<init>(MemberIndex.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaStaticClassScope.computeMemberIndex(LazyJavaStaticClassScope.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaMemberScope$memberIndex$1.invoke(LazyJavaMemberScope.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaMemberScope$memberIndex$1.invoke(LazyJavaMemberScope.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:314)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:355)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaMemberScope$properties$1.invoke(LazyJavaMemberScope.kt:229)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaMemberScope$properties$1.invoke(LazyJavaMemberScope.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:385)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:428)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaMemberScope.getProperties(LazyJavaMemberScope.kt:292)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.scopes.JetScopeSelectorUtil$5.get(JetScopeSelectorUtil.java:92)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.scopes.JetScopeSelectorUtil.getFromAllScopes(JetScopeSelectorUtil.java:123)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.scopes.ChainedScope.getProperties(ChainedScope.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.scopes.ChainedScope.getProperties(ChainedScope.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.tasks.collectors.VariableCollector.getNonExtensionsByName(CallableDescriptorCollectors.kt:109)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.tasks.collectors.FilteredCollector.getNonExtensionsByName(CallableDescriptorCollectors.kt:156)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.tasks.TaskPrioritizer.addCandidatesForNoReceiver(TaskPrioritizer.kt:229)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.tasks.TaskPrioritizer.doComputeTasks(TaskPrioritizer.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.tasks.TaskPrioritizer.computePrioritizedTasks(TaskPrioritizer.kt:75)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallResolver.resolveSimpleProperty(CallResolver.java:123)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getVariableType(CallExpressionResolver.java:101)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getSimpleNameExpressionTypeInfo(CallExpressionResolver.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getSelectorReturnTypeInfo(CallExpressionResolver.java:271)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getQualifiedExpressionTypeInfo(CallExpressionResolver.java:296)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.visitQualifiedExpression(BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.java:683)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.visitQualifiedExpression(BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.java:88)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitDotQualifiedExpression(JetVisitor.java:270)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetDotQualifiedExpression.accept(JetDotQualifiedExpression.java:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.visitJetElement(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.visitJetElement(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:36)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitExpression(JetVisitor.java:162)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitQualifiedExpression(JetVisitor.java:262)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitDotQualifiedExpression(JetVisitor.java:270)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetDotQualifiedExpression.accept(JetDotQualifiedExpression.java:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:136)
    ... 144 more
```

Comment: This is a bug in the Kotlin IDE plugin. Please report it to our issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: All compiler internal errors should be reported as @AndreyBreslav mentions, you can do so then add the issue number / link here so others (including yourself) can track the status.

Comment: This issue was fixed, and does not occur in current Kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine in 0.10.206.7 version of kotlin plugin

Comment: That version is M10 and beyond.